# How can I compute $\langle x|e^{-a \hat{p}^{2}}| x^{\prime}\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators, fourier-transform

I want to compute $$\langle x|e^{-a \hat{p}^{2}}| x^{\prime}\rangle$$
I think
$$e^{-a \hat{p}^{2}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left[-a \hat{p}^{2}\right]^{n}}{n!}$$

and I know that $\langle x|\hat{p}| x^{\prime}\rangle=-i \hbar \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \delta\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)$.
So, $$\left\langle x\left|e^{-a \hat{p}^{2}}\right| x^{\prime}\right\rangle=\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n !}\left[a \hbar^{2} \frac{d^{2}}{d x^{2}}\right]^{n}\right) \delta\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)$$
Is it right?
I have no idea to the next step.
How does operator $\frac{d^{2 n}}{d x^{2 n}}$ act to $\delta\left(x-x^{\prime}\right)$ ?

Answer (score 4):

You want to do this in momentum-space to avoid making a mess:
\begin{aligned}
\langle x|e^{-a \hat{P}^2}|x'\rangle = \int dp \langle x|e^{-a \hat{P}^2}|p\rangle\langle p|x'\rangle = \int dp~ e^{-ap^2} e^{ip(x-x')}
\end{aligned}